# Explain why $Cov(X-E(X\mid Y), Y) =0 $

Tags: probability-theory, covariance

$$Cov(X-E(X\mid Y), Y) =0 $$

Above $Cov$ denotes Covariance.

My textbook says above identity always holds, but I can't figure why it is so.

Any hint or advice?

Also, if $Cov(X-E(X\mid Y), Y) =0 $ always holds, Does $Var(X-E(X\mid Y), Y) =0 $ always hold?

Comment: Your second question (about the variance) is not correctly formulated. Variance takes one argument, e.g. $Var(X)$ or $Var(E[X\mid Y])$. There is not such thing as $Var(X,Y)$.

Comment: right.. will remain it without edit for later viewers.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(X-\mathsf E(X|Y),Y)&=\mathsf E(X-\mathsf E(X|Y)-\mathsf EX+\mathsf E\mathsf E(X|Y))(Y-\mathsf EY)\\
&=\mathsf E(X-\mathsf E(X|Y))(Y-\mathsf EY)\\
&=\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(Y\mathsf E(X|Y)) -\mathsf EX\cdot\mathsf EY +\mathsf EY\cdot\mathsf E\mathsf E(X|Y)\\
&=\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(XY) -\mathsf EX\cdot\mathsf EY +\mathsf EY\cdot\mathsf EX\\
&=0
\end{align}
Here several properties of conditional expectations are used. For example, $\mathsf E\mathsf E(X|Y)=X$ and $Y\mathsf E(X|Y)=\mathsf E(XY|Y)$.

Comment: EE(X|Y) denote Expectation of E(X|Y) I think, but when calculates it, is it integrated by x or y ? Still I am confusing with myself..

Comment: @Beverlie In general we do not compute a expectation by integrating by $X$, $Y$ or any particular random variable. Instead, we integrate on the probability space $\Omega$ w.r.t. the probability measure. But if the function being integrated is $X$-measurable, then by change of variables, we may integrate w.r.t. the measure induced by the distribution function of a r.v. $X$. In this sense, we may consider the second expectation being an integration by $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the law of total expectation $$\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[X \mid Y]] = \operatorname{E}[X]$$ the nested expectations on the LHS are such that the innermost expectation is with respect to $X$ for a fixed $Y$, and the outer is taken with respect to $Y$.  That is to say, $\operatorname{E}[X \mid Y]$ is a random variable that is a function of $Y$.  For the sake of conceptual convenience, call this function $g_X(Y) = \operatorname{E}[X \mid Y]$, and it obeys the property that $\operatorname{E}[g_X(Y)] = \operatorname{E}[X]$.

With this in mind,
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Cov}[(X-\operatorname{E}[X \mid Y]), Y] 
&= \operatorname{E}[X - g_X(Y), Y] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(X - g_X(Y))Y] - \operatorname{E}[X - g_X(Y)]\operatorname{E}[Y] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[XY - g_X(Y)Y] - (\operatorname{E}[X] - \operatorname{E}[g_X(Y)])\operatorname{E}[Y] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[XY] - \operatorname{E}[g_X(Y)Y] - (\operatorname{E}[X] - \operatorname{E}[X])\operatorname{E}[Y] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[XY] - \operatorname{E}[g_X(Y)Y].
\\
\end{align*}$$
From here, it seems that no further simplification is possible.  But since $$g_X(Y)Y = Y \operatorname{E}[X \mid Y] = \operatorname{E}[XY \mid Y],$$ it follows that $$\operatorname{E}[g_X(Y) Y] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[XY \mid Y]] = \operatorname{E}[XY],$$ where the rightmost expectation is with respect to $X$ and $Y$ jointly.  Thus the covariance is zero as claimed.